# Ошибка в disnake class (селект меню)

Tags: python, discord

У меня вот тут проблема :

```
    
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(label="Дворник", description="Начальная работа \"Подметаем!\""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Дальнобойщик", description="Уже лучше \"Груз везем!\""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Грузчик", description="Уже намного лучше \"Грузим вещи!\""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Работник отеля", description="Продвинутая работа \"Обслуживание клиентов!\""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Строитель", description=" Мега работа \"Строим!\""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Бизнес-мен/вомен", description="Лучшая работа \"Бизнес!\""),
        ]
        
        super().__init__(
            placeholder="Выбор работы",
            min_values=1,
            max_values=1,       
            options=options
        )
    async def callback(self,inter: discord.Interaction):
        await inter.response.send_message(f"Вы выбрали работу: {self.values[0]}.")


class VakView(discord.ui.View):
        
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.add_item(Vak())
@bot.command(aliases=["работы","вакансия"])
async def vak(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Выбор работы",desciption=f"**{ctx.author.name}**,выберите работу!",colour=color)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb,view=VakView())
```

Делал я на disnake(и да не обращайте внимание на то что там написано discord , я просто там в начале импорте написал

```
import disnake as discord
```

Вот моя ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in command vak:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 173, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 372, in vak
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desciption'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/bot_base.py", line 591, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 914, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/core.py", line 182, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desciption'
```

Answer (score 0):

Читайте ошибку. Указано что аргумента `desciption` не существует. Так и есть.

Вы допустили ошибку в слове `desciption`, пропущена буква `r` >> `description`

```
@bot.command(aliases=["работы","вакансия"])
async def vak(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Выбор работы",description=f"**{ctx.author.name}**,выберите работу!",colour=color)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb,view=VakView())
```

Comment: Спасибо не заметил,даже когда читал ошибку